# Finding negative numbers in a field in ILog

Tags: business-rules, ilog, jrules

I have a following requirement in Ilog Jrules,

Having an Integer field that contains both positive and negative numbers.
Requirement is to loop through the Integer field, find and remove the negative sign in the negative numbers.
It sounds simple but I could n't find a way to to this.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve created the following function in BOM to XML mapping and passing all the incoming integer field values through this, which solved the problem.

if (integer < 0)
    return integer * -1;
else
    return integer;

Answer (score 0):

(Supposing that XArray is an input/output Array of Integer in your rule project)
You can create a rule like this:

```
definitions 
set 'x' to a Number from  XArray;
if
x is less than 0
then
set x to -x;
```

PS: don't forget to add the rule in a ruleTask (with RetePlus Alogorithm: default) in the main ruleflow.